# How to write good mail to HR if I forgot to bring swipe card

Tags: professionalism, email

I forgot to bring swipe card while coming to office. So I want to write mail to my HR but not getting proper words or good sentence to write mail. As of now I have written

> Hi Maam, Today I forgot to bring swipe card please add my attendance
>   for today. My coming time is 10:10.
>
> Thank you.

Please suggest me good mail.

Comment: Why downvotes? The user has showed some effort, the user is a new contributor, and the user has well-defined problem. To some people the issue might be trivial but who said that only life-changing dilemmas can be posted here?

Comment: @kukis I think the problem is it reads as a "please phrase this email for me"; which is hard to give an objectively correct answer to (also writing the grammatical English may be more suited for ELL.StackExchange). The other issue is that how to deal with a lost swipe card is a fairly company-specific issue. Of course, that doesn't mean that OP's problem is stupid *(and personally I don't find this particularly worse than a number of existing questions about emails and resumes)*.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere - I am already in office, when I came to entrance, I checked my card, it was not there to swipe. Than I called my friend he came to the gate he swipe his card then I went inside.

Comment: @kukis The problem is basically the same as with "What laptop should I buy for gaming?" posted on SuperUser. It's a shopping list, only instead of laptop models you get letter variations.

Comment: Great question!!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about :

Dear Sir/Madam,

Today I forgot to bring my swipe card. Please include (or update) my attendance for today.

My arrival time was 10:10. You can check with xxxx (add your supervisor).

Thank you.

If you know exactly who to write to then :
Dear Mr Jones, or Mrs Jones or Ms Jones (as appropriate)
or if you know them well enough :
Dear Fred ...

Answer (score 4):

personally I would recommend to call, if it is the first time. Be sure to tell them that you that you made a mistake and that you give your best to avoid it in the future. Ask them what kind of information they need from you and to whom you should write such an email, maybe there is somebody specifically responsible for you.

Often a personal contact is the best method. The person from HR knows you and if you are happy and friendly they will not be angry or anything with you but be (more or less) happy that you aknowledged them ;-)

Stay positive, happens to the best ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, that is already good e-mail. If you want to be sure you do the right thing, ask your manager about what you are supposed to do if that happens again.

With better English, it becomes:

> Dear Sir / Madam,
>
> Today I forgot to bring the swipe card. Please add my attendance for today.
>
> I arrived in the office at 10:10.
>
> Thank you.

Comment: It's poor - there are grammar errors...

Comment: well, you are right about the errors. I answered more related to the practical part of the message.